# How to split wordpress the_content() ; in to few parts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to split my "the_content();" using word count. 
First section show 400 words and Google add
Second section show rest of word and show google add like wise. Any idea ?

Comment: you should use the shortcode for showing the ad because if you split  using word count your page may break because of html conflict

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use following code if it helps you

```
add_filter('the_content','filterContentForGoogleAds',10,1);
function filterContentForGoogleAds($content){
  $contentToReturn = '';
  $mycontent = '</br>Your google ads code here</br>';
  $CompleteContent = $content;
  $ContentArray = explode (' ',$CompleteContent);
  $ContentCLength = count($ContentArray);
  $firstHalfEnd  = ceil($ContentCLength/2);

  for ($i=0; $i < $firstHalfEnd; $i++) { 
    $contentToReturn .= ' '.$ContentArray[$i];
  }

  $contentToReturn .= $mycontent;



  for ($i=$firstHalfEnd; $i < $ContentCLength; $i++) { 
    $contentToReturn .= ' '.$ContentArray[$i];
  }

  return $contentToReturn;
}
```